# Convert a CURL command into ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, curl

I have a simple requirement of uploading a .csv file on the server.
I need to convert the below CURL command into ASP.NET:

```
curl -k -3 -vvv -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST --form "file=@xyz.csv" "https://myURL.com/lists.json?auth_token=XXXXXXXXX"
```

I tried it simply as:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://myURL.com/lists.json?auth_token=XXXXXXXXX");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Response.Write(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

lblMsg.Text = responseFromServer;

reader.Close();

response.Close();
```

But it's throwing an error: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out

Line 18: `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();`

I am not even aware of how to pass the file name (xyz.csv) and the other parameters such as -vvv or -3 or -H while running this command through ASP.NET.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Kishori R.

Comment: You haven't properly converted it. That CURL does a `POST` for a start, you're just doing a `GET`. You might find `WebClient` a better fit for this, makes some of these tasks a little easier.

Comment: Hi Lloyd, thanks for reply. I also tried it by setting request.Method = "POST"; But it didn't work for me.